# How to show the covers of the album?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using this code to show the cover of the songs in the listview:

```
package com.xrobotx.love.musicalbums;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;
    Context mContext;

    public SongAdapter(Context c, List<Song> theSongs){
        songs=theSongs;
        songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return songs.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //map to song layout
        RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout)songInf.inflate
                (R.layout.song_layout, parent, false);

        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        TextView durationView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_duration);
        ImageView coverView = (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_cover);

        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);

        //get title and artist strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        durationView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) currSong.getDuration()),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) currSong.getDuration()) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) currSong.getDuration()))));


        if(currSong.getCover() != null){
            Glide.with(mContext).load(currSong.getCover()).override(50, 50).into(coverView);
        }


        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }

}
```

Not all covers are displayed correctly. Some covers infact are black.
Why ?

EDIT:

This is the code to get the Cover:

```
private static String getCoverArtPath(long albumId, Context context) {
    Cursor albumCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)},
            null
    );
    boolean queryResult = albumCursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = null;
    if (queryResult) {
        result = albumCursor.getString(0);
    }
    albumCursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `Glide` code seems fine. Did you make sure that all your images are available? Try adding an error image `Glide.with(mContext).load(currSong.getCover()).override(50, 50).error(R.drawable.errorDrawable).into(coverView);` to see if there are errors during loading

Comment: Maybe the url to the cover is returning a black image =]. Are you sure that all the cyrrSon.getCover() are returning a valid image?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori If I use your code, then it doesn't show black images but the R.drawable.errorDrawable images. So is there an error ? However some images are displayed correctly. Maybe do I need to clear the cache ?

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira No I am not sure. How can I check ?

Comment: Well, you can simply check the Url of the cover that shows blank and put it inside your browser. Try to debug your adapter to see what url is getting the blank images

Comment: Are you loading the images from the web (are your images urls)?

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira The logs tell me that the black images and the correct album images are in this directory: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/ but the directory "com.android.providers.media" doesn't exists. How is this possible ?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori No I am using the MediaStore to get the album images. As I said, not all images are black. Some are displayed correctly :)

Comment: I have just edited the question and added the code to retrieve the album.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this. Glide network requests like any other request **it fails sometimes**

So the solution i found is to make another request on failure.

```
 Glide.with(context)
.load((currSong.getCover())
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(width, height) {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
         //handle Bitmap
         coverview.setBitmap(resource);
     }

     @Override
     public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
         Glide.with(mContext).load(currSong.getCover()).override(50, 50).into(coverView);

     }
});
```